# STM32 hardfault at free

Tags: c, malloc, microcontroller, free, stm32

I am developing an application with STM32L476 (without FreeRTOS). I am using SW4STM32 and STM32CubeMx. I am using SDMMC with Fatfs in my application. Currently I am seeing a hardfault when I free memory.

These are my stack and heap details as per linker file

```
/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20018000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x7E20;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x1FA0; /* required amount of stack */
```

`0x20003248` is the address at which crash occurs (is the address which I am freeing)

I tried to debug the issue by following this link [Cortex-M3 Hard Fault - find cause](http://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/)

This is what I get at hardfault:

```
SCB->HFSR = 0x40000000
Forced Hard Fault
SCB->CFSR = 0x00008200
```

but I couldnt conclude anything

Comment: [This page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Cihcfefj.html) includes a description of all the CFSR register bit values.  You have `BFARVALID` and `PRECISERR` set.  Read the descriptions and then examine the `BFAR` register value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HardFaults like this - in `free` or even `malloc` - usually indicate a problem with your memory being corrupted in some way. The most common cause is either double `free` on the same memory address or overwriting data in memory, e.g. writing past the end of some kind of buffer.

Regarding the second point - although this is implementation dependent - the general approach for `malloc` is to store some additional information that it uses internally for future calls to `malloc` or `free`. These are things like size of the chunk that actually got allocated, information about next chunk in memory etc. This information in the implementation I've checked was stored right before the memory address you're given as a return value from `malloc`. If you then overwrite this data - for example by writing past a buffer that got allocated before this address - the next call to `free` that frees this memory is going to fail in unexpected ways, often resulting in a HardFault.

Having said that and given the limited information you've provided, all I can suggest is to go through the code that writes data to memory - mostly code writing to arrays allocated with `malloc`. Limit the code to a minimal case that still causes HardFault and debug it. Possibly set some data breakpoints (write). `free` failing when freeing memory may not (and in this case, it likely doesn't) necessarily indicate a problem with that particular portion of memory, but rather an adjacent one.

Comment: I had a hardfault at malloc. It seemed the driver was likely writing a byte or 2 extra into the allocated region. Simply requesting a few extra bytes at allocation time has stopped my hardfault error.